# Finding the frequency of each word in a list and displaying the result in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

'''
def freq(str):

```
# break the string into list of words  
str = str.lower().split()          
str2 = [] 

# loop till string values present in list str 
for i in str:              

    # checking for the duplicacy 
    if i not in str2: 

        # insert value in str2 
        str2.append(i)  
          
for i in range(0, len(str2)): 

    # count the frequency of each word(present  
    # in str2) in str and print 
    print('Frequency of', str2[i], 'is :', str.count(str2[i])) 
    print(str(list))
```

'''

right now the result for the freq('Hell is hell') is
Frequency of hell is : 2
Frequency of is is : 1

how to display the result in dictionary format like:
('hell:2','is:1')

Comment: [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted seems faulty to me. Why do you check for duplicates if you want count of all the words and what is the use of `str2`. Again, you are checking for count in `str2` which doesn't has duplicate words, it will give count as 1 for each word.

You can try the following code for the result you desire:

```
def freq(str1):
    str1 = str1.lower().split()
    result = dict()
    
    for word in str1:
        result[word] = str1.count(word)
        
    return result
```

PS: It is not a good practice to use keywords as variables in your code, `str` is a built-in class.

Comment: Thank  you sir for the very simple and crisp solution. Will definitely work on improving my coding methods